# mark Jenkins Job as Failed based on the console log

Tags: jenkins

I have tried log parser plugin but it didn't work for me 
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Log+Parser+Plugin

Comment: Is it a freestyle job or pipeline? How did you set up configuration for log parser?

Comment: I got the solution, we can use exit $? 
this will mark Jenkins as failed when application end abnormally